# Android: Double selection of objects in WebApp Android (JQUERY)

Tags: javascript, java, android, webview, android-webview

I develop WebApp Android based on existing JavaScript applications. My application - it opens the link WebView file index.html

```
    mWebView.setVerticalScrollBarEnabled(false);
    mWebView.setHorizontalScrollBarEnabled(false);
    mWebView.setLongClickable(false);
    mWebView.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLACK);

    mWebView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    mWebView.getSettings().setDomStorageEnabled(true);
    mWebView.getSettings().setSupportZoom(false);
    mWebView.getSettings().setSupportMultipleWindows(false);
    mWebView.getSettings().setBuiltInZoomControls(false);
    mWebView.getSettings().setAppCacheEnabled(false);

    mWebView.addJavascriptInterface(new AppCustomInterface(this), "Android");
    mWebView.loadUrl(URL);
```

**The problem is that when you press the up / down / left / right  instead of one object there are two object. One aspect stands out as it should, and the other stands a thin yellow outline. When I JS application runs in Chrome it works fine.**
Help remove the second selection. Tnx!

Answer (score 0):

Solved a problem. Dual Focus appeared on the clickable objects described in JQuery. If you turn off the menu at the facilities JQuery dual focus disappears.